# Typo3 +TV not rendering content elements

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I have installed typo3, templavoila and mapped a template.

Everything works fine, except my content elements. They just don't appear. They did before I installed templavoila and mapped a template.

Also, when using

```
10 = RECORDS
10 {
  tables = tt_content
  source = 9
}
```

it does not give me any output.

even nothing with:

```
10 = RECORDS
10 {
  tables = tt_content
  source = 9
  conf.tt_content = TEXT
  conf.tt_content.value = TEST
}
```

Does anyone have a clue as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `10` - it's a "global" variable, or a property of your page ?

Comment: for testing purposes, a property of `page = PAGE`. When I replace the `RECORDS` cobj with a `TEXT` cobj I do get output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we got it to work. Don't know what I did wrong, but I guess I learned not to do it again.

I'll put the "solution" here since someone might find it helpful and lose more than a day over this like I did.

Solution:
`copy an existing content element in list mode, pasted it on a page via page mode`

This was to test if that would do anything. Guess what, everything worked again. Not only the newly copied element but also ALL other test elements created via different ways on different pages and storage folders.

Thank you all for helping and thinking along.

Comment: Afterwards I had many problems getting the default FE loginform to work. It showed but whatever I did, it did not let us log in.
Finally I grabbed a clean Typo3 install of version 4.5.13 and all went as it should. I'm not touching 4.6.x for a while :-)
Thanks everyone for the help!!

Comment: This means, you just hit a cache issue. Clear all caches would have helped you out too.

Answer (score 2):

You must include the css styled content static template in your TS template.

Comment: Please use the template analyzer to check the order of inclusions (hind: you can click render whole template).

Answer (score 1):

In your ts page object you need to assign it to the templavoila object.

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = USER
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? I don't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes I have done that. I do get output from the template. It's just the content elements that don't render somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the page, where tt_content is situated is not visible to regular visitor ?

In this case, following snippet will help.

```
10 = RECORDS
10.tables = tt_content
10.source = 9
10.dontCheckPid = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have already checked this and it did not help. Though none of the content elements on the site work, not only the RECORDS object.

Comment: Did You mapped content output in TV ?

Comment: Yeah, did that too. AFAIK I have done everything as one would normally do it. Haven't changed anything about that mapped element either. All content is set to column 0 as well - the way TV likes it.